# Difference of certain elements from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists and I want to take the difference keeping the first elements of the sublists ( `X1,X2` below) intact which are the same in both lists. Is there any easier way to do it without explicitly going through each list element and taking the differences except the first one? I tried

```
listA = {{1}, {X1, a, b}, {X2, c, d}};
listB = {{0}, {X1, a0, b0}, {X2, c0, d0}};
MapThread[{First[#1] , Rest[#1] - Rest[#2]} &, {listA, listB}]
```

Output:

```
{{1, {}}, {X1, {a - a0, b - b0}}, {X2, {c - c0, d - d0}}}
```

Expected output:

```
{{1}, {X1, a - a0, b - b0}, {X2, c - c0, d - d0}}
```

How do I remove these unwanted braces?

Comment: `Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
 MapThread[{First[#1], Rest[#1] - Rest[#2]} &, {listA, listB}]`

Comment: I did use `Flatten` but as `//Flatten` which removed all the braces which is why it did not work.

Comment: `MapThread[{First[#1], Sequence @@ (Rest[#1] - Rest[#2])} &, {listA, 
  listB}]`

Comment: If you have at least version 12.1 then consider also `MapThread[{First[#1], Splice[Rest[#1] - Rest[#2]]} &, {listA, listB}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 MapThread[
 Flatten@{First[#1], 
 If[SameQ[Rest[#], {}], Nothing, Rest[#1] - Rest[#2]]} &, {listA, listB}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = {{1}, {X1, a, b}, {X2, c, d}};
listB = {{0}, {X1, a0, b0}, {X2, c0, d0}};
```

Expected output:

`{{1}, {X1, a - a0, b - b0}, {X2, c - c0, d - d0}}`

---

```
listA - listB // ReplacePart[{i_, 1} :> listA[[i, 1]]]
```

`{{1}, {X1, a - a0, b - b0}, {X2, c - c0, d - d0}}`